# D3D12 ClearRenderTargetView

Tags: directx-12

Passing a float array and receiving the warning, "The clear values do not match those passed to resource creation."

1 Works without warning

2 Does not and I tried using the GetFloatArray() method and still receive the warning

Render Target Format is:

```
clearValue.Format = DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
```

My CColor object:

```
float RGBA[4];

float* GetFloatArray()
{
    return RGBA;
}
```

The ClearRenderTargetView(s):

```
// #1
globalObjects->videoDevice->commandList->ClearRenderTargetView(
   globalObjects->videoDevice->swapChainRenderTargets[globalObjects->videoDevice->frameIndex]->handle,
   CColorCornflowerBlue.GetFloatArray(), 0, nullptr);

// #2
const float c[4] =
{ 
    CColorLovelyPurple.RGBA[0],
    CColorLovelyPurple.RGBA[1],
    CColorLovelyPurple.RGBA[2],
    CColorLovelyPurple.RGBA[3]
};

commandList->ClearRenderTargetView(renderTargets[globalObjects->videoDevice->frameIndex]->handle,
c, 0, nullptr);
```

Any ideas or if others are having the same problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us the code that creates the render target view (`renderTargets[globalObjects->videoDevice->frameIndex]->handle`), but when you create it, the clear value can be set in `D3D12_CLEAR_VALUE`:

```
D3D12_CLEAR_VALUE clearValue = {};
clearValue.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM_SRGB;
clearValue.Color = c;
```

Just change the `.Color` to match the color in the call to `commandList->ClearRenderTargetView()`

Comment: Added  clearValue.Color[0] = 0.0F;
 clearValue.Color[1] = 0.0F;
 clearValue.Color[2] = 0.0F;
 clearValue.Color[3] = 1.0F;
and same result.

Comment: Seems that the swapchain format is ok with it but not an additional render target.
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I didn't understand a second render target view and was using it incorrectly.  For those of you trying to make an overhead it is NOT a second render target but a 2D image instead.  My overall goal was an overhead not multiple render targets.

```
commandList->CopyResource(texture->texture.Get(), renderTargets[globalObjects->videoDevice->frameIndex]->resource.Get());
```